# Querying the index for if a field exists in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use DynamoDB to keep track of whether a particular unique identifier has been processed. I get this identifier from an external system and then store it in DynamoDB. Later on when I need to do processing, I get a list of identifiers and I want to check to make sure that a given identifier is not in the database.

I do this via:

```
// to store
updateItem({
  TableName: "t1",
  Key: {
    Id: {
      S: id
    }
  }
})

// to check
queryAsync({
  TableName: "t1",
  KeyConditions: {
    CrawlName: {
      ComparisonOperator: "EQ",
      AttributeValueList: [{
        S: id,
      }],
    },
  },
})
```

While this does work, it seems a little bit ridiculous to me to simply query the index for an existing item. I think the SQL equivalent would be something like `SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE Id = :id`.

Is there a better way for me to store/retrieve a unique ID?

Comment: Why not performing a `GetItem` and checking if an item is returned? You can even send a `ProjectionExpression = #id` to lower the response payload size to a minimum.

Comment: @MatiasCicero no reason why not; I guess that is what I'm asking :D

Comment: Well, it's cheaper, it's faster, and it's easier. I guess these are enough reasons :P

Comment: @MatiasCicero what about how I create the key? is this okay?

Comment: Functionally, yes. An `UpdateItem` operation will create the item if the specified key does not exist. Semantically, no. If your explicit intention is to **create** a new element, then I shall recommend you to use `PutItem`

Comment: Watch out for race conditions if you have multiple threads or machines running this logic at once. If you do, stick with conditional updates (that fail if the item already exists) instead of queries.

Comment: @Chris in this case it shouldn't actually matter if an update is applied multiple times since it only has one value, but this is a good thing to keep in mind for the future

Comment: It's not about different values, but about two different threads assuming a value hasn't been processed yet because they both ran a query at the same time, then both inserted to the db at the same time. Using a conditional update instead will notify one of the threads that the value already exists.